Share object with another thread without `move`
How do I safely share this response.audio_file to a different thread?
    // Network call

    thread::spawn(move || {
        prepare_result_files(&response.audio_file).await;
    });
    //prepare_result_files(&response.audio_file).await;
    Ok(response) // It doesn't work because the `response` was partially moved.
}

I tried to implement the Copy trait to AudioFile, but then I couldn't because most of the types cannot implement the Copy trait:
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[tsync]
pub struct AudioFileResponse {
    pub code: i32,
    pub message: String,
    pub audio_file: AudioFile,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[tsync]
pub struct AudioFile {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub status: Status,
    pub results: Option<Vec<ResultFile>>,
}


The new spawn-out thread doesn't modify the audio_file. It is simply read-only access. Any pointers?

Please elaborate on the sharing you want between the threads. Does either thread need to modify the data? Can you modify the fields of response to store audio_file behind a useful abstraction?

The simplest way to share objects between threads is to wrap them with Arc and/or Mutex.

Do both threads need to access audio_file?

Do you want to wait on prepare_result_files before returning the response? What is response - can you change it? Also, if prepare_result_files is async then just calling it in a thread like that probably won't do you much good - Futures generally have to be .await-ed to do anything.

@nanofarad, I updated my question.

@kmdreko No, I don't, hence the other thread approach because I want to return the response immediately.


The new spawn-out thread doesn't modify the audio_file. It is simply read-only access. Any pointers?

The simplest, most straightforward, but less-efficient way would be to clone the data. (Note that the efficiency loss might be totally irrelevant given the size of the data). You'd need to ensure that AudioFile implements Clone:
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
#[tsync]
pub struct AudioFile {
...

You may need to ensure that ResultFile is also Clone (String and i32 are already Clone). Note that if ResultFile is Clone, then Option<Vec<ResultFile>> automatically becomes Clone as well, so all of our fields are Clone and we can derive Clone for AudioFile.
Then, pass the clone:
    let cloned_audio = response.audio_file.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        prepare_result_files(cloned_audio).await;
    });


Another approach would be to wrap the audio_file data behind an Arc - essentially a reference-counted holder of data. When you clone an Arc, you increase the reference count and get a second Arc pointing to that same data, and once the last Arc is dropped, the data is dropped as well.
That would be perfect - except tsync doesn't seem to support Arc, even if serde does - although I don't have a way to check this for sure. However, even if it's not possible, I still think it's worth showing you this data structure as it's quite useful in concurrent/async Rust in general.
If this way were possible, you'd need to enable the rc crate feature for serde, store an Arc<AudioFile> in audio_file, make prepare_result_files take an Arc<AudioFile>, and then pass in a clone of the Arc:
    let cloned_audio = response.audio_file.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        prepare_result_files(cloned_audio).await;
    });

(you'll notice that this is the exact same code - in the previous example, we cloned the data, in this example, we clone the Arc)

You can use an Arc and a Read Write Lock.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html
https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html
so for
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[tsync]
pub struct AudioFile {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub status: Status,
    pub results: Option<Vec<ResultFile>>,
}

you should wrap the whole response in an Arc<RwLock<>
let response = Arc::new(RwLock::new(audio_file));

let response_clone = Arc::clone(&response);

thread::spawn(move || {
    let audio_file = response_clone.read().await.unwrap();
    prepare_result_files(&audio_file);
})

Note that you will get a read only copy of audio_file
if you choose to, you can use .write() instead for, however, this will lock the file until the lock is released.

This doesn't work. I couldn't return the original response in the Ok(response)

RwLocks can't be serialized

If the original thread does not need to access audio_file, you can take() it and avoid a clone:
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Default)]
#[tsync]
pub struct AudioFile {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub status: Status,
    pub results: Option<Vec<ResultFile>>,
}

// Network call

let audio_file = std::mem::take(&mut response.audio_file);
thread::spawn(move || {
    prepare_result_files(audio_file).await;
});
Ok(response)

You can also use std::mem::replace() or wrap audio_file in an Option if it is not Default.

Aside from deriving Clone or adding smart pointers such as Arc etc., scoped threads lets you borrow from the outside scope in this fashion:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html
    thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| {
            prepare_result_files(&response.audio_file); // If it were sync
        });
    });
    
    Ok(response)

The borrow ends at the end of the scoped threads, once all threads have joined.
You may want to look for crates that do scoped tasks in async, otherwise this will execute the async code:
    thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| async {
            prepare_result_files(&response.audio_file).await;
        })
        .join()
    })
    .unwrap() // Thread join result
    .await;

    Ok(response)

